# Fall Back Menu for main menu? Advice needed

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress, and am still trying to learn the in's and out's in much respect to this well known CMS.

And please forgive me if my question sound way off base, but nevertheless I have to ask.

I am wanting to know, if I should or must have a Fallback for main menu?

I had registered the wp_nav_menu() within my function.php file:

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'xxxxxx' ),
) );
```

And here is the callback within my header.php file:

```
<nav>            
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'Primary', 'menu' =>  'Primary','container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="main">%3$s</ul>'  )); ?>
</nav>
```

Like I said, I am new. So please, any help will be much welcome.

And if you could, please respond with an example. I'm not that bright! Lol....

Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a fallback. The default is all pages, or wp_page_menu (all pages under this post type).

You can override this by setting the value to false. Using your example:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'Primary', 'menu' =>  'Primary','container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="main">%3$s</ul>','fallback_cb'=> false  ));
```

Wait... I think I misread. So let me clarify. The first function you posted registers the menu within wordpress. Now you will see it within the menu tab. You still need to create a menu and activate within the ui, and place the second function where you want it to display. The 2nd function is the actual result of the menu registered and created.

My first comment was in reference to what happens if you don't put anything in the wordpress menu UI. It fallsback by default to display all pages. You can disable this.